# POST Request to HTTPS(SSL) url from Android/Java

Tags: java, android, django, ssl, https

I am pretty new to Java and Android. Working on Python all the time.
I am trying to make an Android Apps via Android Studio BumbleBee (2021.1.1 Patch 3) that can make GET and POST request to a https(SSL) server. The server is run by Django 3.2, deploy on IIS(version 10.0) powered by Window Server 2019.
GET requests are fine but POST requests are not!

What i am trying to do is to make a POST request to login to the website.
My idea is to send a GET request to obtain the csrftoken and csrfmiddlewaretoken for subsequent POST request. (From my understanding, Django POST requires csrfmiddlewaretoken in the POST data and csrftoken in the cookies).

Everything works fine when i tried on http://localhost:8000 OR i use @csrf_exempt decoration on both HTTP and HTTPS(SSL) server.

But the actual server which run by Django is HTTPS(SSL) instead of HTTP and i want to remain the csrf function.

Since i keep failing on Android Studio, I tried to make POST request to https by Java(on Eclipse IDE Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)) and it keeps returned an error of 403.

I tried with SSL Socket Factory in Java but still it does not work. I am not sure if i am doing the right way..

Can anyone guide me, if possible step by step or share the relevant knowledge to me, on how to make connection from JAVA(and Android Studio) to HTTPS Server?

Many thanks in advance!

Below is my code on Java:

```
package stream;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class csrf {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String baseUrl = "ANY https url";//for example https://www.somehttpsurl.com/login

        try {
            URL url = new URL(baseUrl);
            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // set the header
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "zh-cn,zh;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content_type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "");
            conn.connect();
            
            // get the login form
            String data = "";
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                data = inputStreamToString(conn.getInputStream());              
            } else {
                System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
            }
            conn.disconnect();
            //get cookie
            String cookie = getRespCookie(conn);
            
            //get csrfmiddlewaretoken from form
            String csrfmiddlewaretoken = extractCsrfmiddlewaretokenFromString(data);
            
            //prepare POST params
            String params = "csrfmiddlewaretoken="+csrfmiddlewaretoken+
                    "&username=someone"+"&password=somepassword";
            
            //get SSL?
            TrustManager[] tm = { new MyX509TrustManager() };
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null,  tm,  new java.security.SecureRandom());
            System.out.println(sslContext.toString());
            
            SSLSocketFactory ssf = sslContext.getSocketFactory();       
            
            //starting to post with data
            URL url1 = new URL(baseUrl);
            HttpsURLConnection conn1 = (HttpsURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
            conn1.setSSLSocketFactory(ssf);
            conn1.setRequestMethod("POST");         
            conn1.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
            conn1.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "zh-cn,zh;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
            conn1.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36");
            conn1.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            conn1.setRequestProperty("Content_type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn1.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
            conn1.setDoInput(true);
            conn1.setDoOutput(true);            
            conn1.connect();
            
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(conn1.getOutputStream());
            pw.write(params);
            pw.flush();     
            pw.close();         
                    
            if (conn1.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                data = inputStreamToString(conn1.getInputStream());
                System.out.println(data);
            } else {            
                InputStream err = conn1.getErrorStream();
                
                try (var in = new Scanner(err)) {
                    System.out.println(in.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("\n");
                }
            }
            
            
            conn1.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    
    public static String getRespCookie(HttpURLConnection con) {
        String cookie = "";
        
        Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = con.getHeaderFields();
        if (headerFields != null) {
            List<String> cookies = headerFields.get("Set-Cookie");
            if (cookies != null) {
                for (String cookie_item:cookies) {
                    cookie += cookie_item + ";";
                }
            }
        }
        return cookie;
    }

    public static String extractCsrfmiddlewaretokenFromString(String data) {
        String csrfmiddlewaretoken = "";
        int length = 64;//csrfmiddlewaretoken length is 64
        String keyword = "name=\"csrfmiddlewaretoken\" value=\"";
        
        try {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken = data.substring(data.indexOf(keyword)+keyword.length(),
                    data.indexOf(keyword)+keyword.length()+length);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return csrfmiddlewaretoken;
    }

    public static String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String str = "";
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len = 0;

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            byte[] dataArray = baos.toByteArray();
            str = new String(dataArray, "utf-8");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return str;
    }

}

class MyX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");` can you use TLSv1.3 instead of SSL & give it a go?

Comment: @AshishPatil I tried. Still doesn't work...